# Lambda function in list comprehension returning a function

Tags: python, list

I have a list comprehension with a lambda like so, where i add the word to the list if its length is more than one character:

```
   dict['Company {}'.format(counter)]=[lambda x: len(x)>1 for x in sent[0].split()]
```

But it outputs a function instead of a list:

```
Company 13 [<function get_maps1.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000001F18E4191E0>, <function get_maps1.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000001F18E419268>, <function get_maps1.<locals>.<listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000001F18E4192F0>]
```

How can i print its contents?

Comment: No, the output **is a list of functions**. Why did you expect anything else? Note, these functions are probably not working the way you expet them to anyway, since `x` will refer to the *last `x` in the loop*, but that is another matter...

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a list of lambdas, because that's exactly what you are doing with this line of code:

```
[lambda x: len(x)>1 for x in sent[0].split()]
```

What you probably intended to do is this instead:

```
[len(x)>1 for x in sent[0].split()]
```

which results in a list of booleans